# Вычленение из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, функции

[image: Проверка списка до и после]

```
import xlrd
import openpyxl
i=int(input())
g = []
while i !=0:
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook('lessons.xls',formatting_info=True)
    sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
    Polgod = int(input())
    if Polgod == 1:
        for k  in range (1, 120):
            g.append(sheet.cell(3, k).value)
    print (g)
    for j in g:
       if j == ("Н") or j == ("+ ") or j == (""):
          g.remove (j)
    print (g)
```

Я решил написать программу. Для части этой программы мне нужна строка из exel. Я подключил нужные модули, все отлично работает, но когда я создаю список, в него добавляются и пустые ячейки строки. Поэтому я написал алгоритм их удаления из списка(в самом конце) , но он работает очень странно. До какого-то момента убирает пустые клетки, а потом просто игнорит их, "Н" и "+" вообще не трогает :(. Что с этим алгоритмом не так?

---

[image: Фрагмент таблицы]

Я бы скину файл, но не нашел кнопку:(

Comment: Приведите пример таблицы из `lesson.xls`. Первые 10 строк.

Comment: Во первых операция удаления сама по себе затратная по времени. Во вторых удаление в цикле ни в одном языке не делается, так как при удалении становятся невалидными итераторы.  Нужно не удалять, а добавить значения нужных ячеек в новый список.

Comment: Например вот так: g = [j for j in g if j not in ["Н","+ ",""]]
print (g)

Comment: Т.е. пересоздали список g.

Comment: Нельзя при переборе списка удалять из него элементы. Поэтому у вас и возникли проблемы. JaponDemon показал как можно получить `g` через генератор списка